# Discrepancies between lmerTest and lme4 results

Tags: regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have a certain value as the DV (dependent variable), and I am interested in the effect of BMI on the DV. I have multiple observations for the DV (i.e., every subject responds five times), so I wanted to fit a mixed model (for repeated measures of each ID).

So what I did was:

1. Use Bodo Winters tutorial - compute the difference between a complicated and a simpler model.
2. Use `lmerTest`

Now, the results are very different, and I cannot figure out why.

1. ```
   m1 <- lmer(value  ~ BMI + Dummy + (1|ID), data=data)
   m2 <- lmer( value ~ BMI + (1|ID), data=data)
   anova(m1, m2)
   ```

Here, my results are highly significant

2. ```
   require(lmerTest)
   m3<-lmer(value ~ BMI  + (1|ID), data=data)
   anova(m3)
   ```

Here, my results are not significant at all. Sorry, that I cannot provide a reproducible example, this discrepancy only happens with the BMI effect, not with my other effects of interest. So now I wonder: why
Do you have any suggestions, somewhere I maybe made a mistake?

Here is the output I get

```
> m1 <- lmer(value ~ BMI + (1|ID), data=data, REML=FALSE)
> m2 <- lmer(value ~ 1 + (1|ID), data=data, REML=FALSE)
> anova(m1, m2)
Data: data
Models:
..1:value ~ 1 + (1 | ID)
object: value ~ BMI + (1 | ID)
       Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
..1     3 2188.1 2201.0 -1091.1   2182.1                             
object  4 2149.4 2166.6 -1070.7   2141.4 40.687      1  1.787e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

AND

```
anova(lmer(value ~ BMI + (1|ID), data=data, REML=FALSE))
Analysis of Variance Table of type 3  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF  F.value Pr(>F)
BMI 0.17868 0.17868     1   110 0.059873 0.8072
```

Comment: if you can't provide a reproducible example, can you at least show us the output?? otherwise you're unlikely to get any useful help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I added the output. I hope it helps. I now tried it with Alku's idea, but I get the same as for a dummy. Is it possible, that the difference version does not work for continous data? So far, I always used categorical data and get very similar results for lmertest and the difference version.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you are considering the wrong models for the LR tets. For testing BMI :

m1 <- lmer(value  ~ BMI + (1|ID), data=data)

m2 <- lmer( value ~ 1 + (1|ID), data=data)

anova(m1, m2)

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this.  Using a very similar example:

```
library("lme4")
m1 <- lmer(Reaction  ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
m2 <- update(m1, .~.-Days)
anova(m1,m2)
## refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
## Data: sleepstudy
## Models:
## m2: Reaction ~ (1 | Subject)
## m1: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
##    Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
## m2  3 1916.5 1926.1 -955.27   1910.5                             
## m1  4 1802.1 1814.8 -897.04   1794.1 116.46      1  < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Now with `lmerTest`:

```
library("lmerTest")
anova(lmer(Reaction  ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy,
           REML=FALSE))
## Analysis of Variance Table of type 3  with  Satterthwaite 
## approximation for degrees of freedom
##      Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
## Days 162703  162703     1   162  170.45 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Plain old `anova(refitML(m1))` gives a similar result in this case:

```
## Analysis of Variance Table
##      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
## Days  1 162703  162703   170.45
```